# Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH causes terminal app to not open

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, environment-variables, libraries

I set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in my `~/.profile` in order for my oracle client to work.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/lib
```

I succeeded in getting the oracle client to work, but I am unable to launch the normal terminal app, although xterm still works.

Is there a special way to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` that will keep Ubuntu happy?

Comment: Could you please also provide the output of `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in your question?

Comment: :/home/grayjo/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/client_1/lib

Answer (score 0):

This seems to apply...

Note: You can only set this environment variable inside an interactive shell. [ie a terminal ] Since Ubuntu 9.04 Jaunty Jackalope, LD_LIBRARY_PATH cannot be set in $HOME/.profile, /etc/profile, nor /etc/environment files. You must use /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf configuration files. See Launchpad bug #366728 for more information.